# Git fetch from root user failed in linux

Tags: linux, git

I am trying to fetch the git project using root user, i.e root@

```
+ git fetch ssh://<server>:29418/myproject.git --prune refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
Cloning into bare repository '.'...
root@<server>: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

if i change to user, i.e uid@

> - git fetch ssh://server:29418/myproject.git --prune refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master

it works fine.

I copied /home/uid/.ssh to /root/.ssh, still i am facing same error.

Question is how can i fetch git project when i change to root user. I can also fetch explicit uid of ssh,

> git fetch ssh://uid@:29418/myproject.git --prune refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master

Which also works, but i am creating a jenkins script which should work for all user. So i want to fetch as root user.

Comment: If the remote git repo is just a folder on the server (i.e. no server software such as GitLab is in play) then give the full path to the repository

Comment: The problem is on the git server side I guess. The public key that you added for your user doesn't match the one you're trying to fetch the repo with.

Comment: @MarkoE if i change to uid@ : Then same command is working

Comment: What is the `sshd_config` option `PermitRootLogin` set to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should share the content of your `~/.ssh/config` file

I would suggest to check the `User` you are using for the key

e.g.
if you have in `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host myserver.com
IdentityFile /path/to/may/key
```

and that's working for user "myusername" (i.e. `/home/myusername/.ssh/config`)
when copied to root's home, then it may be missing the user name
e.g.
modified in `/home/root/.ssh/config`:

```
Host myserver.com
User myusername
IdentityFile /path/to/may/key
```